# Pandas apply speed on large datasets.

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, lambda

I have a table in pandas that has two columns, `QuarterHourDimID` and `StartDateDimID` ; these columns give me an ID for each date / quarter hour pairing. For instance for January 1st, 2015, at 12:15PM the `StartDateDimID` would equal `1097` and `QuarterHourDimID` would equal `26`. This is how the data I'm reading is organized.

It's a large table that I'm reading using `pyodbc` and `pandas.read_sql()`, ~450M rows and ~60 columns, so performance is an issue.

To parse the `QuarterHourDimID` and `StartDateDimID` columns into workable `datetime` indexes I'm running an apply function on every row to create an additional column `datetime`.

My code reading the table without the additional parsing is around 800ms; however when I run this apply function it adds around 4s to total run time (anywhere between 5.8-6s a query is expected.) The `df` that is returned is around ~45K rows and 5 columns (~450days*~100quarter-hour-parts)

I am hoping to more efficiently rewrite what I've written and get any input along the way.

Below is the code I've written thus far:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pyodbc

def table(network, demo):
    connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=OURSERVER;DATABASE=DB"
    sql = """SELECT [ID],[StartDateDimID],[DemographicGroupDimID],[QuarterHourDimID],[Impression] FROM TABLE_NAME
        WHERE (MarketDimID = 1
        AND RecordTypeDimID = 2
        AND EstimateTypeDimID = 1
        AND DailyOrWeeklyDimID = 1
        AND RecordSequenceCodeDimID = 5
        AND ViewingTypeDimID = 4
        AND NetworkDimID = {}
        AND DemographicGroupDimID = {}
        AND QuarterHourDimID IS NOT NULL)""".format(network, demo)

    with pyodbc.connect(connection_string) as cnxn:
        df = pd.read_sql(sql=sql, con=cnxn, index_col=None)


    def time_map(quarter_hour, date):
        if quarter_hour > 72:
            return date + timedelta(minutes=(quarter_hour % 73)*15)
        return date + timedelta(hours=6, minutes=(quarter_hour-1)*15)

    map_date  = {}

    init_date = datetime(year=2012, month=1, day=1)

    for x in df.StartDateDimID.unique():
        map_date[x] = init_date + timedelta(days=int(x)-1)

    #this is the part of my code that is likely bogging things down
    df['datetime'] = df.apply(lambda row: time_map(int(row['QuarterHourDimID']),
                                                   map_date[row['StartDateDimID']]),
                                                   axis=1)
    if network == 1278:
        df = df.loc[df.groupby('datetime')['Impression'].idxmin()]

    df = df.set_index(['datetime'])

    return df
```

Comment: I would try to add a virtual column on the SQL Server side using SQL Server's `DATEADD()` function and `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE` - it should be much faster

Comment: Thanks Max. This definitely did the trick. I had an enormous improvement in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just to post an example of the date-time conversion being performed in SQL rather than pandas and the time mock-up, using the above code and yielding a mean time of 6.4s/execution, I was able to rewrite the code entirely in SQL and got a mean time of 640ms/execution.

The updated code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

SQL_QUERY ="""
SELECT [Impressions] = MIN(naf.Impression), [datetime] = DATEADD(minute,td.Minute,DATEADD(hour,td.Hour,CONVERT(smalldatetime, ddt.DateKey))) 
FROM [dbo].[NielsenAnalyticsFact] AS naf
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DateDim] AS ddt
ON naf.StartDateDimID = ddt.DateDimID
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TimeDim] as td
ON naf.QuarterHourDimID = td.TimeDimID
WHERE (naf.NielsenMarketDimID = 1
    AND naf.RecordTypeDimID = 2
    AND naf.AudienceEstimateTypeDimID = 1
    AND naf.DailyOrWeeklyDimID = 1
    AND naf.RecordSequenceCodeDimID = 5
    AND naf.ViewingTypeDimID = 4
    AND naf.NetworkDimID = 1278
    AND naf.DemographicGroupDimID = 3
    AND naf.QuarterHourDimID IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY DATEADD(minute,td.Minute,DATEADD(hour,td.Hour,CONVERT(smalldatetime, ddt.DateKey)))
ORDER BY DATEADD(minute,td.Minute,DATEADD(hour,td.Hour,CONVERT(smalldatetime, ddt.DateKey))) ASC
"""

%%timeit -n200
with pyodbc.connect(DB_CREDENTIALS) as cnxn:
    df = pd.read_sql(sql=SQL_QUERY,
            con=cnxn,
            index_col=None)
200 loops, best of 3: 613 ms per loop
```